# Django Rest Framework DjangoModelPermissions not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Why the DRF permission class **DjangoModelPermissions** allow every users to perform all requests like
**POST**, **PUT**, **DELETE** even those user i didn't manually assign them the **add**, **change**, **delete** permissions from my django admin. they are allowed to be only view the objects but why the are getting all unsafe request **POST**, **DELETE**... ?

**Views.py**

```
class HotelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Hotel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HotelSerializer
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissions]
```

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions',
        ]
}
```

Comment: Did you managed to find the answer?

Comment: This solution solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67847583/11828749

Answer (score 1):

The `viewsets.ModelViewSet` does not implement `delete()`, `post()`, etc. methods itself. If you want to use it, you have to implement them yourself.

Instead, you should use Django REST `generics`. Please refer to Django REST framework docs:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using DRF generic views where you can use specific views like ListAPIView/ RetrieveAPIView for GET requests, CreateAPIView for POST, UpdateAPIView for PUT, etc.