# DjangoModelPermissions is not working for view level permission in my API application

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I have created an API and I am trying to provide permissions to the views in my API app. I have assigned users to groups with permissions in my admin portal and then I am using **DjangoModelPermissions** in my views so that the permissions behave according to the admin portal which is not working.
When I use **IsAdminUser** then its working it is preventing other users to read the view. but for **DjangoModelPermissions** it is not working.

In simple terms I want to block access to views for few users even after assigning permissions and passing this value **DjangoModelPermissions** in permission glass that user is still able to get access for that view.

Users and Groups in my admin group
One **super_user** assigned to **Developers** groups with all permissions.
One **Testuser** assigned to **Language** groups with only access to language view.

The code for Model

````
```Python
from django.db import models

class Paradigm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# Create your models here.
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    paradigm = models.ForeignKey(Paradigm,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # this method will help us to get the actual Name insted of object name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Programmer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
````

The Code for view

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from .models import Language, Programmer, Paradigm
from .serializers import LanguageSerializer, ParadigmSerializer, ProgrammerSerializer
from  rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission, IsAdminUser, DjangoModelPermissions

# Create your views here.
class LanguageView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Language.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LanguageSerializer
    
    # This below line is not working
    permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissions]

class  ParadigmView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Paradigm.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ParadigmSerializer
    # This below line is not working
    permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissions]


class  ProgrammerView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Programmer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProgrammerSerializer
    #This Below line is working only for Admin user
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
```

Please help me here as I am new to Django.
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

create permissions.py file as:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import DjangoModelPermissions
class D7896DjangoModelPermissions(DjangoModelPermissions):
    perms_map = {
        'GET':['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
        'OPTIONS': [],
        'HEAD': [],
        'POST': ['%(app_label)s.add_%(model_name)s'],
        'PUT': ['%(app_label)s.change_%(model_name)s'],
        'PATCH': ['%(app_label)s.change_%(model_name)s'],
        'DELETE': ['%(app_label)s.delete_%(model_name)s'],
    }
```

extend the default DjangoModelPermissions, and add this perms_map
also, update your views.py as:

```
from .permissions import D7896DjangoModelPermissions
class  ParadigmView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Paradigm.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ParadigmSerializer
    permission_classes = [D7896DjangoModelPermissions]
```

this worked for me :)

Comment: Thanks a Lot @Noah this was really helpful solved this issue. Can u share me any references for this permissions file any sort of documentation which u referred with.

Comment: I don't think this is documented in rest-framework
I found this while going through the code.

Comment: It's referenced here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions:~:text=For%20example%2C%20you,code%20for%20details.

Comment: also https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/2da473c8c8e024e80c13a624782f1da6272812da/rest_framework/permissions.py#L177